# Thermodynamic and mechanical work

Tags: thermodynamics, work, potential-energy

Well till now I don't think that there is any clear cut distinction between thermodynamic work and mechanical work.
If there is any difference between these two terms please give some answer

So the thing is for thermodynamic work **can I use this equation which says**

**W = -∆U**
where W= Work and ∆U=Change in Potenial Energy.

So can I use it or not to use it?

If the equation do not stands for thermodynamic work then please give a described reason(not compulsory just want to know is the equation good or not)

Thanx

Comment: The first law of thermodynamics clearly states that heat is a form of energy.

Comment: Better: The first law of thermodynamics clearly states that *heat transfer* is a form of *work*.

Comment: @MritunJay, your equation for work equaling negative change in potential energy might be correct, but you need to put a bit more effort into defining your process.  If you are dealing with an adiabatic process, and if work exiting the process is considered to be positive, then the equation is correct.

Comment: @David yup I am dealing with adiabatic process considering it to be positive and CuriousOne Thanx for that point just forgot and count_to_10 need time to read that duplicate.Thanx to all for the help. Last teensy bit of doubt that should I take ∆U  equals to final minus initial or initial minus final

Comment: Final - Initial.  If the final internal energy is lower than the initial internal energy, the negative delta-U indicates a temperature drop.

Answer (score 0):

The first law of thermodynamics tells us that, for a closed thermodynamic system, $$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta (PE)=Q-W$$  In this equation, what you are calling $\Delta U$ is, in thermodynamics symbology, what they call $\Delta (PE)$.  In addition, in this equation, $\Delta U$ is the change in *internal energy* of the system (typically just the random kinetic energy of the molecules), Q is the heat added to the system, and W is the work done by the system on its surroundings.

From this equation, under certain circumstances, $$\Delta (PE)=-W\tag{your equation}$$
So your equation applies when there is no change in internal energy of the system, no change in macroscopic kinetic energy of the system, and no heat added to the system.

Comment: Well there is a doubt should i consider ∆U=final minus initial or initial minus final just asking

Comment: If you are referring to internal energy, then final minus initial.

Comment: And if it is for potential energy then in what conditions should i subtract final from initial or vice versa

Comment: It depends on whether you define work done *on* the system as positive or whether you define work done *by* the system as positive.

Comment: You mean that if i take work done by the system positive then  i should do $\delta$U= final minus initial and if i take work done on the system positive then i should do $\delta$U = initial minus final please reply sorry for any inconvienence

Comment: If we define W as the work done by the system on the surroundings, then the first law of thermodynamics reads $$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta (PE)=Q-W$$.  If we define W as the work done by the surroundings on the system, then the first las of thermodynamics reads $$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta (PE)=Q+W$$